# How to COMBINE 4 JSON objects/files to create ONE JSON file

Tags: json, rest, jstree

OK, this is probably a REAL simple request.

But, I have 4 JSON files, well, I get JSON when doing a GET to a

//some IP address/some directory/some sub directory/name of folder

So I get back let's just say, NETWORKS, SITES, RESOURCES, COMPONENTS

Each one below NETWORKS is the CHILD...

Ok, next:  I need to COMBINE these JSON files to populate JSTree (from jstree.com)

I have a basic JSON file like this and it WORKS beautifully:

(NOTE: the ID's below are irrelevant and DO NOT match in the REAL examples farther down here.)

The intent here is to JOIN all four JSON objects which I'm getting through a RESTful environment to JAVA API's that GET the data from the database.

```
[
{
    "data": "Network 1",
    "metadata": {"id" : "n1"},
    "children": [ {  

            "data": "Site 1",
            "metadata": {"id" : "s1"},
            "children": [ {  

                "data": "Resource 1",
                "metadata": {"id" : "r1"},
                "children": [ 

                        {
                            "data": "Component 1",
                            "metadata": {"id" : "c1"}
                        },
                        {
                            "data": "Component 2",
                            "metadata": {"id" : "c2"}
                        },
                        {
                            "data": "Component 3",
                            "metadata": {"id" : "c3"}
                        } ] } ] },

                    "Site 2",

                    "Site 3",

                    "Site 4"]
}
]
```

Here's my dilemma:

I need to combine the following JSON files:  SITES, RESOURCES, and COMPONENTS

Simple right? Not so much.

Here's a sample of each of the lower level JSON Objects:

NETWORKS:

```
[
  {
    "id": "23ef0d23-0d8d-4466-98da-81ef30791773",
    "notes": "This is a network for network 1",
    "name": "n1"
  },
  {
    "id": "b4b46748-511a-49bf-9d22-8da014c76cc2",
    "notes": "This is a network for network 2",
    "name": "n2"
  },
  {
    "id": "678b4a01-a6a6-449f-966d-c50c74964729",
    "notes": "This is a network for network 3",
    "name": "n3"
  },
  {
    "id": "8e2822b1-49a8-498e-979b-2849cfa82148",
    "notes": "This is a network for network 4",
    "name": "n4"
  }
]
```

SITES:

```
[
  {
    "id": "05683e7b-e471-4417-bead-317cfcbfaf30",
    "name": "s1",
    "networkId": "23ef0d23-0d8d-4466-98da-81ef30791773",
    "notes": "This is site 1"
  },
  {
    "id": "de8d654c-f9c4-4a4e-8742-32794b218b54",
    "name": "s2",
    "networkId": "23ef0d23-0d8d-4466-98da-81ef30791773",
    "notes": "This is site 2"
  },
  {
    "id": "16b2b1cf-2991-4717-ae65-2158700fa95d",
    "name": "s3",
    "networkId": "8e2822b1-49a8-498e-979b-2849cfa82148",
    "notes": "This is site 3"
  }
]
```

RESOURCES:

```
[
  {
    "id": "26db6a18-5099-4117-9adb-b8c808a3c478",
    "networkId": "23ef0d23-0d8d-4466-98da-81ef30791773",
    "siteId": "05683e7b-e471-4417-bead-317cfcbfaf30",
    "name": "r1",
    "notes": "This is Resource 1"
  },
  {
    "id": "26ad2b53-f4b2-41c1-a618-d9e710452b7f",
    "networkId": "23ef0d23-0d8d-4466-98da-81ef30791773",
    "siteId": "05683e7b-e471-4417-bead-317cfcbfaf30",
    "name": "r2",
    "notes": "This is Resource 2"
  }
]
```

And Finally, COMPONENTS:

```
[
  {
    "id": "6e8d13ad-9eb6-4213-bf84-a6e91d2e1460",
    "resourceId": "26ad2b53-f4b2-41c1-a618-d9e710452b7f",
    "siteId": "05683e7b-e471-4417-bead-317cfcbfaf30",
    "networkId": "23ef0d23-0d8d-4466-98da-81ef30791773",
    "name": "Component 1",
    "notes": "This is my very first component - Yay!"
  },
  {
    "id": "8f18cca3-378e-4f9b-8a39-eb2285fa61fd",
    "resourceId": "26ad2b53-f4b2-41c1-a618-d9e710452b7f",
    "siteId": "05683e7b-e471-4417-bead-317cfcbfaf30",
    "networkId": "23ef0d23-0d8d-4466-98da-81ef30791773",
    "name": "Component 2",
    "notes": "This is my Second component - Yay!"
  },
  {
    "id": "539370a6-577f-477d-a6ea-d45efd7e65aa",
    "resourceId": "26ad2b53-f4b2-41c1-a618-d9e710452b7f",
    "siteId": "05683e7b-e471-4417-bead-317cfcbfaf30",
    "networkId": "23ef0d23-0d8d-4466-98da-81ef30791773",
    "name": "Component 3",
    "notes": "This is my Third component - Yay!"
  }
]
```

Ultimately, when combined, it's GOT to look like the very first JSON example which WORKS for JSTree.

Thank you all for helping.

Regards